# Question about Notes on Operator Algebra

Tags: operator-algebras

This question is concerned with the last line of [these notes](http://galileo.phys.virginia.edu/classes/751.mf1i.fall02/CoherentStates.pdf) by M. Fowler titled "Coherent States of the Simple Harmonic Oscillator."

I understand the things before that but I don't see how the last line comes about.

Thank you,
George

Comment: Making the question a little more self-contained is both friendly to potential answerers, and avoids the question becoming unanswerable due to something happening to the link. By adding the name and author of the notes I intend to make them searchable in case the link changes.  (If I were more ambitious I might type the last line and a little context to actually make the question self contained.)  (This comment was deleted and reposted because of a typo.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have that $e^{A+B}=e^Ae^Be^{-\frac12[A,B]}$. Exchanging the roles of $A$ and $B$ you get
$$
e^Be^Ae^{-\frac12[B,A]}=e^Ae^Be^{-\frac12[A,B]},
$$
so
$$
e^Be^A=e^Ae^Be^{-\frac12[A,B]}e^{\frac12[B,A]}=e^Ae^Be^{-\frac12[A,B]}e^{-\frac12[A,B]}
=e^Ae^Be^{-[A,B]}.
$$
This, of course, provided that the original requirement of $[A,B]$ commuting with both $A$ and $B$ holds (so that the original identities are valid).

Comment: You are welcome, and don't worry: we all have a long story of missing the obvious.

Answer (score 0):

So, assume we know $e^{A+B} = e^A e^B e^{-\frac12[A,B]}$, then using $A+B=B+A$, this also must hold:
 $$e^A e^B e^{-\frac12[A,B]} = e^{A+B} = e^{B+A} = e^B e^A e^{-\frac12[B,A]} $$